# Constructor injection best practices

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, dependency-injection, ninject

I have 3 service components, one low-level service responsible for some kind of data serialization, one in the middle responsible for coordinating saves/loads, and one MVC Controller responsible for API publication.

Each of the 3 components logically refers to the other "below" it. The middle service has another parameter, which is known at runtime, based on request data. From this 3 components the controller and the middle service are represented by classes (doesn't make sense to introduce interfaces because nothing to mock), and the lowest level is repesented by an interface, making it available to unit-test the middle service or the controller. I'd like to use DI (specifically Ninject) to build my controller class. My question is if any kind of best practice exists for handling this scenario. Currently I see two way of implementation. (The validations, proper implementations are ommitted for the clarity.)

First of all, here is a sample implementation of the middle service and the lower level interface.

```
public interface ISerializer {
  void Serialize(object data);  
}

public class MyService {
  private string _dataId;
  private ISerializer _serializer;
  public MyService(string dataId, ISerializer serializer) {
    _serializer = serializer;
    _dataId = dataId;
  }
  public bool CanProcess(MyDTO data) {
    ...
  }
  public void DoSomeProcessing(MyDTO data) {
    ...
  }
}
```

### Version 1: inject the whole middle service to the controller as a factory

```
public class MyController : Controller {
  private Func<string, MyService> _myServiceFactory;
  public MyController(Func<string, MyService> myServiceFactory) {
    _myServiceFactory = myServiceFactory;
  }
  ...
  [HttpPost]
  public JsonResult Process(string dataId, MyDTO model) {
    using (var myService = _myServiceFactory(dataId)) {
      ...
      if (myService.CanProcess(model))
        myService.DoSomeProcessing(model);
      ...
      return Json("ok");
    }
  }  
}
```

### Version 2: Injecting directly the lower-level interface to the controller, and instantiate the middle service "manually".

```
public class MyController : Controller {
  private ISerializer _serializer;
  public MyController(ISerializer serializer) {
    _serializer = serializer;
  }
  ...
  [HttpPost]
  public JsonResult Process(string dataId, MyDTO model) {
    using (var myService = new MyService(dataId, _serializer) {
      ...
      if (myService.CanProcess(model))
        myService.DoSomeProcessing(model);
      ...
      return Json("ok");
    }
  }  
}
```

Which one is more proper, or should I choose a completely different solution?

Comment: Why not just let Ninject handle everything? As long as you provide all the binding references, Ninject will initialize what the controller needs when it loads and follow the dependency chain all the way down.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Yes, I would do that but I have that tricky runtime contructor argument on MyService. As I'm watching the code, I'm about to prefer the factory version...

Comment: Well it depends. Even if a dependency is a value type, it can be resolved by Ninject if you can tell it how to do so. You'd just have to define a method that could return this value somehow and tell Ninject to use that. However, if this is something that you truly can't resolve at a higher level, then dependency injection, at least for your controller, is out of the question anyways. Long and short, this is an architecture problem.

Comment: That value is coming from the request as you can see in the code. Probably I have a higher level design problem, I'm thinking about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I like my services to be stateless, so I don't like the idea of passing `dataId`
to the service's constructor. When services are stateless they are safer. You can call their methods not worrying if they are currently in a valid state. It also makes it easier to test and mock them. You can also reduce the amount of used memory, as you only need one instance of a stateless service.

If you moved `dataId` to `DoSomeProcessing` as a parameter you would be able to easily instantiate MyService with Ninject and the proper implementation of ISerializer would be injected automatically.

However if you insist on passing it to the constructor "Version 1" is quite close to what I'd consider good. Factory is a nice trick to let DI inject dependencies, when there are also data parameters needed in the constructor. I would inject `MyServiceFactory` to the controller. I'd create another class for it:

```
public class MyServiceFactory : IMyServiceFactory // an interface to me able to mock it if needed
{
    ISerializer _serializer;
    MyServiceFactory(ISerializer serializer){  // here Ninject can inject the dependency
        _serializer = serializer;
    }

    IMyService Create(int dataId){ // here you can pass additional parameter
        return new MyService(dataId, _serializer);
    }
}
```

This way you can easily avoid hard dependencies and make the code more maintainable and more testable.

"Version 2" is wrong. If you ever want to test your controller or replace MyService with another implementation - you are stuck. You'll have to do a lot of tedious refactoring  (depending on the amount of usages). And finally you'll end up with something similar to what I suggested above. :)

Comment: Thank you, I was about to come to similar conclusions. I was storing dataId as a member variable because that service is full of little methods, all of them needing that variable. But I think I'll need to refactor it somehow, because I agree with you about stateless services. Thanks again.